# I can't get htmlpurifier to allow anchors (a tag with name attribute)

Tags: tinymce, htmlpurifier

I really can't get htmlpurifier to allow name attributes on a tags. I want to allow tinyMCE to function with anchors. I suppose the name attribute is deprecated an id should be used, but tinyMCE produces name attributes. Is there somehow I can either transform them into id="" or accept them?

Following the [docs](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) I try this but it doesn't work

```
require_once( 'HTMLPurifier.standalone.php' );

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$config->set( 'HTML.Doctype'        , 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional'  );
$config->set( 'Cache.DefinitionImpl', null                      ); // remove this later!
$config->set( 'Core.CollectErrors'  , true                      );

$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition( true );

$def->addAttribute( 'a', 'name' , 'ID'    );
// $def->addAttribute( 'a', 'name' , 'CDATA' ); // does not work either
// $def->addAttribute( 'a', 'name' , 'Text'  ); // does not work either


$purifier = new HTMLPurifier( $config );

$purifier->purify( '<a name="test"></a>' );

echo $purifier->context->get( 'ErrorCollector' )->getHTMLFormatted( $config );


// output:

//     Error Line 1, Column 0: name attribute on <a> removed
```

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-id.html

(Oh, and remove the custom HTML definition and declarations.)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for responding. I can get it to accept ID's, but tinymce at least in wp does not generate anchors with the id attribute. It generate name="something" attributes. I was wondering if they can be rewritten or accepted.

Comment: ok, now realised that you don't need the html def. Does that mean that there is no way to restrict the permission of id's to just anchor elements?

Comment: As in, you don't want to allow people to specify id=""? Well, you could forbid it from your attribute list.

Comment: Mainly I would like to have the `<a name="something">mlkj</a>` translated into `<a id="something">mlkj</a>` because that is what tinymce produces. And as a second question I was wondering about the possibility of allowing `<a id="something">` but not `<div id="something">`. Because I see a sense in allowing footnote with anchors, but don't see much sense in allowing id's on something else.

Comment: I answered the latter question. Former is not supported by HTML Purifier, though I imagine it'd be an easy AttrTransform.